# The chain rule, partial derivatives and general functions

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am revising for my first year Calculus examination. The following question is on a past paper and I am given the solution, however I am struggling to make sense of it:

> Let $V(x,y)$ be a differentiable function and set
>    $$W(r,\varphi):=V(r\cos\varphi,r\sin\varphi).$$
>    Apply the chain rule to show that
>    $$
>  \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\right)^{\!2}+
>  \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}\right)^{\!2}=
>  \left(\frac{\partial W}{\partial r}\right)^{\!2}+
>  \frac{1}{r^2}\left(\frac{\partial W}{\partial \varphi}\right)^{\!2}
>  $$

I am told that $V_r=V_x*x_r+V_y*y_r$ but do not see why.

Comment: I cannot see the picture.

Answer (score 0):

The multivariable chain rule tells us that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial W(r,\phi)}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial V(r \cos \phi,r \sin \phi)}{\partial x} \cos \phi + \frac{\partial V(r \cos \phi, r \sin \phi)}{\partial y} \sin \phi
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial W (r,\phi)}{\partial \phi} =
\frac{\partial V(r \cos \phi,r \sin \phi)}{\partial x} (-r \sin \phi) + \frac{\partial V(r \cos \phi, r \sin \phi)}{\partial y} (r \cos \phi).
\end{equation}

Using these equations, it's easy to check that the expression
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial W(r,\phi)}{\partial r} \right)^2 + \frac{1}{r^2} \left(\frac{\partial W(r,\phi)}{\partial \phi} \right)^2
\end{equation}
simplifies to
\begin{equation}
\left( \frac{\partial V(r \cos \phi, r \sin \phi)}{\partial x} \right)^2
+ \left(\frac{\partial V(r \cos \phi, r \sin \phi)}{\partial y} \right)^2.
\end{equation}